# How to read data in elementary stream

Tags: mpeg-2

I have to read the eiss table in the elementary stream. How to read the elementary stream and get access to the data.Are there any API's available in DVB , javatv or ocap

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a standard that defines the format of the data you are trying to read? Something like the ISO/IEC 13818-1 for the Transport Stream and Packetized Elementary Stream. If you do, you can find out exactly how to read the data and what it means. If that is not what you are asking, please be more specific on your question.

There are a couple open source projects related to DVB that I know of:

- [TSFileSource](http://nate.dynalias.net/dev/tsfilesource.rails)
- [MediaPortal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/)

Also possibly of use, but I'm not sure how open the source is:

- [DVBCore](http://www.dvbcore.com/)

Note, I've never used any of these personally, so I'm not sure how useful they will be, especially at the elementary stream level. It could be starting point though.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check [Project-X](http://sourceforge.net/projects/project-x).